# Why does pointing to a vector element's member lead to segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

I have a class `Game` and a struct `NamedGame`. `NamedGame` has two member variables as seen below:

```
  struct NamedGame {
    Game game;
    std::string name;
  };
```

I then have a `vector` with `NamedGames`:

```
std::vector<NamedGame> games;
```

A pointer shall point to the currently active game:

```
  Game *currentGame;
```

Now, when I try to point at the last `NamedGame` in the vector `games` as follows:

```
  *currentGame = games.back().game;
```

It leads to a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong, and why is it wrong? I truly appreciate all help!

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Game {};
struct NamedGame {
  Game game;
  std::string name;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<NamedGame> games;
  Game *currentGame;
  *currentGame = games.back().game;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're newing up each `Game` before adding it to `games`?

Comment: You should check that games is not empty before accessing its back

Comment: @quantdev Did you mean `games.begin() != games.end()`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes, basically !games.empty()

Comment: @quantdev: I try `games.back().game.printBoard();`, where `printBoard` draws the game board in the console, which works fine. So that's not the problem.

Comment: Please edit you question to contain [mcve]

Comment: @JCKaz You already got your answer, but please do add [mcve] to your question - in case the answer is incorrect, this will make it possible to provide an answer that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are trying to deference the pointer `currentGame` while it is not initialized:

```
*currentGame = games.back().game;
```

You have to change this line to be:

```
currentGame = &(games.back().game);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Could you please edit your answer to also discuss why `currentGame` should be a reference? I would truly appreciate it!

Comment: @JCKaz this isn't making `currentGame` a reference, it is using `operator &` (pronounced: address-of) to assign to a pointer

Comment: @JCKaz It shouldn't, it's still a pointer. The only difference is that the pointer's initialized without derefercing garbage, which would invoke [ub](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: The original line was trying to call the copy constructor of a pointer that is not pointing to anything yet. When you want to update a pointer you shold not use deference operator (*)

Comment: Thank you all so much! I appreciate it a lot! I changed the question to be minimal and I also edited this answer to correspond to the new variable names etc. that are now in the question. I hope it makes things more simple.

Comment: @JCKaz to elaborate, the line `*currentGame = games.back().game;` reads as: assign the `Game` value gotten from the `NamedGame` at the back of `games` into the location that the pointer `currentGame` points to. The line `currentGame = &(games.back().game);` takes the address of that game, and sets the pointer to that value

Comment: Actually after [mcve] this answer is invalid. That is another reason not to give answer before OP provides enough information.

Comment: I am afraid that his example does not reflect his original problem because it is not complete and it is missing the initialization of the games vector. However the answer is still correct and he already verified that !!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, seg faults are almost always due to dereferencing a null pointer. The culprit, as pointed out by Mahmoud, is most likely due to the following line:

```
*currentGame = games.back().game;
```

Where `currentGame` may not have been initialized yet. Storing the reference of `games.back().game` works, but you should also ask "Why am I using pointers in the first place?" If you are trying boost performance or reduce space used by working with pointers, why not do the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Game {};
struct NamedGame 
{
  Game *game;
  std::string name;
};

int main() 
{
  std::vector<NamedGame> games;
  Game *currentGame

  //Code to initialize NamedGames and push them onto games

  if (NULL != games.back().game)
  {
    currentGame = games.back().game;
  }
}
```

This way, you are still working with pointers, but you are also making it so that the developer SHOULD verify that `Game` is not `NULL` before dereferencing it.

However, if you are using pointers just "for fun", I'd recommend making `currentGame` as type `Game` rather than `Game *` to avoid using pointers all together. If you go that route, I'd also recommend overloading the assignment operator of `Game`, depending on what you are doing with the `currentGame` variable.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? If you were referring to calling games.back() on an empty vector, I assumed he would be stuffing it somewhere else in code. Added a comment for clarification

Comment: Well, my example was made based off the OPs example. His code has UB, however it is still clear what he is trying to show/ask.